# Running PLINQ on Inherited Entities throws AccessViolationException

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce, single-table-inheritance

I came across a bottleneck while testing an application that interfaces with a SQL-Compact 3.5 database with EF.

Usually, when I come across a bottleneck like this, I rework the linq query to reduce the number of linq queries done because re-running the same linq query a dozen times on a database filled with thousands of entries creates a bit of overhead. Then, I use plinq to speed up instantiation time.

Doing this has worked fairly well until I tried to do this with the ShapeEntities table.

The ShapeEntity is an abstract entity which works as the base class for other entities that are nearly identical to each-other. I can't run this with the AsParallel() method.

```
HashSet<Guid> keys ...

var x = 
    from shape in model.ShapeEntities.AsParallel()
    where keys.Contains(shape.ImageKey)
    select shape;

List<ShapeEntity> shapes = new List<ShapeEntity>(x);
```

If I were to remove the AsParallel() from the code above, the query takes about 1.4 seconds to execute when we put it in the list. With the AsParallel() method, I get an AccessViolationException after about 40 seconds. It never gets past instantiation.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to speed this up? I can't do ImageEntity.ShapeEntities because then it turns into 1.2 seconds per ImageEntity.

Comment: I don't think EF contexts are thread-safe. I'm pretty sure that means you can't use them with PLINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Entity framework context is not thread safe. [From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx)

> The ObjectContext class is not thread safe. The integrity of data
>   objects in an ObjectContext cannot be ensured in multithreaded
>   scenarios.

If you are retrieving these entities for for read only purposes you can save few milliseconds by using `NoTracking` `MergeOption`

```
model.ShapeEntitie.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
```

Otherwise implement some paging mechanism.

Comment: What does a paging mechanism mean in this context?

Comment: I've tried the NoTracking option, but it doesn't want to mix and match the MergeOptions. These table's are readonly, but some of the ones further up can be edited at any time.